# Clarification about finding a bilinear form's matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Say $V:=M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $f:V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined $f(X,Y)=Tr(X^TAY)$ for $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix} \, $.
So I want to find the the matrix of $f$ for the standart basis of $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$. If this matrix is $B$ so I know $(B)_{ij}=f(v_i,v_j)$, but I'm kind of getting confused about which $v_i$ I should calculate, and what is the order of $B$ anyway? If someone coukd focus me and explain a bit it'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$, similarly define $v_4,v_5,v_6$. Using your definition of $B_{ij}$, you will get a $6\times 6$ matrix for $B$.

Comment: That what I though, but mustn't $B$ satisfy : $f(v,w)=([v]_B)^TB[w]_B?$ and wouldn't this multiplication be undefined for a $6\times 6$ matrix?

Comment: The $[v]_B$ here will be the coordinates of $v$ in terms of the basis, so it is a $6\times 1$ vector.